# Local NuGet feed (network share) doesn't list packages in VS 2017

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-server

We have a local NuGet feed in a network share accessed via a UNC path `\\server\ourNugetFeed`. This has been working fine in Visual Studio 2015, and we have successfully developed and deployed a couple of custom NuGet packages, as well as been able to download/install them in our projects, using the standard NuGet Package Manager inside VS 2015.

However, VS 2017 (update 2) doesn't see any custom packages listed in NuGet Package Manager, even though we added the custom feed the same way as we did back in VS 2015 (Tools/Options/NuGet Package Sources).

One thing I'm noticing is that VS 2015 has NuGet 3.5.0.1484 while VS 2017 has 
4.2.0.2457.

Another thing we noticed is that changing the path to the nuget feed in VS 2017 from `\\server\ourNugetFeed` to `\\server\ourNuGetFeed\specificPackageFolder` seems to make NuGet Package Manager happy and it DOES show that package. But of course, it doesn't see any other packages because the folder path points to a specific folder.

Another bizarre thing is that copying the whole folder from `\\server\ourNugetFeed` to my local computer `c:\temp\ourNugetFeed` and adding it in VS2017 as a new feed, seems to make it work. Why would it care about the UNC path vs local path?

Any ideas?

Comment: how did you configure the feed? a nuget.config in the solution directory, user-specific nuget.config etc. If any of these contains a `<clear/>` in the source, it may hide ones configured in VS only.

Comment: The only thing I did was to add the feed via VS settings in Tools --> Settings menu. I did not add any other custom feed configurations in the project itself.

Comment: I have this issue also, is there any fix to this?

Comment: We have since then started using the new Package Management feature in TFS 2017 (also available in VSTS). It's a departure from using network file shares to host our local NuGet packages. Visual Studio 2017 seems to work just fine with it, as well as VS 2015. it may not be available to everyone, depending on if you are using TFS/VSTS or not, and whether you have enterprise licenses. But if you do, you might consider this. It's an improvement over nuget file shares.